# Sub query Count SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, subquery

I have this code I need to have row count off. I tried to count it but comes as Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Can you help me with row count, thank you.

```sql
select count((
    select a.GIRIS_ZAMANI, a.CIKIS_ZAMANI, a.PLAKA, a.UCRET, b.KAMERA_ADI
    from ARAC_CIKIS a 
    left join KAMERALAR b 
    on b.KAMERA_ID = a.CIKIS_KAMERA_ID
    where a.CIKIS_ZAMANI between 
        (select cast(cast(sysutcdatetime() as date) as datetime) + cast('00:00:00' as datetime)) and 
        (select cast(cast(sysutcdatetime() as date) as datetime) + cast('23:59:59' as datetime)) and 
        a.UCRET>0
    )
)
```

Comment: Help us help you - please share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it.

Comment: I got a list but just need row count from this chart

Comment: Does query work without count? I would recommend you test query without counting lines, only with some `LIMIT` clause at the end and the add `SELECT COUNT(*)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try below -

```
select count(*)
from
(
select a.GIRIS_ZAMANI, a.CIKIS_ZAMANI, a.PLAKA, a.UCRET, b.KAMERA_ADI  from ARAC_CIKIS a left join KAMERALAR b on b.KAMERA_ID = a.CIKIS_KAMERA_ID
  where a.CIKIS_ZAMANI between cast(cast(sysutcdatetime() as date) as datetime) 
    + cast('00:00:00' as datetime) and cast(cast(sysutcdatetime() as date) as datetime) 
    + cast('23:59:59' as datetime)
 and  a.UCRET>0
) A
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a subquery?

```
select count(*)
from ARAC_CIKIS a left join
     KAMERALAR k
     on bkKAMERA_ID = a.CIKIS_KAMERA_ID
where a.CIKIS_ZAMANI between cast(cast(sysutcdatetime() as date) as datetime) + cast('00:00:00' as datetime) and
                             cast(cast(sysutcdatetime() as date) as datetime) + cast('23:59:59' as datetime) and
      a.UCRET > 0
```